# Determine the oldest file in a directory

Tags: c, directory

I am currently working on a project where I need to find the oldest file from a base name within the directory.

For example the base name of the file may be mylog but it will need to look at all files like mylog_060620121421.txt. From all the files that are mylog_ I need to find out which file is the oldeest, i.e. created first but I can't find how to do this.

I've seen the scandir command to list the file names but I can't see how it can be used to find the oldest date of the file.

Comment: Do you need to do it programmatically?

Comment: It is to be done programatically within the c program. I haven't yet tried anything specific for the oldest file, only the part where using scandir to read all the files and check if the file contains log file and print the name of it, that's about it so far, but I can't find anything for the main part of finding out the oldest file.

Comment: Take a look at getting a substring from your file name for the relevant portion (looks like from 6 - 14) and working from there :) Is this homework?

Comment: I've said that I've got that bit working, the problem I'm having is finding which of the found files is the oldest.

Comment: What's your working platform? Windows or Linux? If Linux, we cannot get creation time of a file IIRC.

Comment: Its on linux, you should be able to get the last modified time as I have done this before. Once the file is created it will never be written to again so the last modified time is suitable for this

Comment: Ok so you have the "creation time" of each file based on its last modified time, now you need to find the oldest one?  Search through them all for the oldest one, I don't see any other way to do it in C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On linux just type in the dir:

```
ls -trl
```

This gives a list, beginning with the oldest file. If you want the name directly you can get it with:

```
ls -tr | head - 1
```

Comment: Thanks this worked great, was just wondering though is there a way that this could also be done on Windows, i am primarily doing it for linux but ideally it should support both. I was thinking the method I am using could have a check to see if its windows or linux and run the correct method for achieving this task.

Comment: The question is tagged with C.  It seems that should be removed, or the other C answer should be accepted.

Answer (score 3):

Use stat()
Run the command "man -S 2 stat" to read more about it.

```
#include <sys/stat.h>
struct stat structstat;
stat(filename, &structstat)
printf("last modified time: %s", ctime(&structstat.st_mtime));
```

where filename is a string/char * representing the file
structstat is a structure of stat which can be found in sys/stat.h

the oldest file will be one with the oldest modification time, structstat.st_mtime unless you have both, then you can use the structstat.st_ctime (status change) for the type breaker...